# C++ Armadillo library gives undefined reference to `arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance'

Tags: c++, cmake, armadillo

I used CMake to build my project and Catch2 to do the testing. The following is my project structure

```
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── compile_commands.json
├── include
│   ├── node.h
│   ├── rrt.h
│   └── tree.h
├── Makefile
├── package.xml
├── scripts
├── src
│   ├── main.cpp
│   ├── node.cpp
│   ├── rrt.cpp
│   └── tree.cpp
├── test
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── test.cpp
└── third_party
    └── catch.hpp
```

In `./CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rrt_ros)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(SOURCES 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/rrt.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/tree.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/node.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rrt.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/tree.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/node.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
    )

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs)
find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

add_executable(
    rrt
    ${SOURCES}
    )

target_include_directories(
    rrt
    PUBLIC
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)


target_link_libraries(rrt ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES})
add_subdirectory(test)
```

In `test/CMakeLists.txt`, I have

```
project(rrt_ros)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp std_msgs)
find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
message("TESTING......" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/rrt.h)

add_executable(rrt_test test.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/rrt.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/tree.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/node.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/rrt.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/tree.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/node.cpp
    )

target_include_directories(
    rrt_test
    PUBLIC
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Armadillo_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../third_party
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include
    )

target_link_libraries(
    rrt_test
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    ${Aramdillo_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

In `rrt.cpp`, I have a function that calls armadillo's sampling function

```
arma::randi<arma::mat>(1, 2, arma::distr_params(1, 10))
```

When I compile the project, it gives me an undefined error:

```
rrt.cpp:(.text._ZTWN4arma23arma_rng_cxx11_instanceE[_ZTWN4arma23arma_rng_cxx11_instanceE]+0x15):  undefined reference to 'arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance'  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, when I comment out `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/rrt.cpp` in `./test/CMakeLists.txt`, it compiles fine.

Comment: I can't tell you what the problem is but I can give you a hint.  "undefined reference" errors are link time errors, so you code compiles, but the linker can't find the listed function.

Comment: There's a typo in the `test/CMakeLists.txt`; shouldn't `${Aramdillo_LIBRARIES}` be `${Armadillo_LIBRARIES}`, or was that an editing mistake while assembling this question?

Comment: @compor: [About the editing]: Please, do not change other's **code style** unless current style is completely a mess or harms readability a lot. If multi-line sequence is enclosed into parenthesis, position of the close parenthesis (after the last symbol or at the new line) is a *matter of choice*. (E.g. I find a new line is the better place for close parenthesis). Do not edit other's code just for make it following your favorite code style.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Please do not assume my preferences. It's ***not*** my favourite coding style, it saves vertical scrolling real estate on a website. There's a point for conciseness, brevity and frugality.

Comment: "... it saves vertical scrolling real estate on a website. There's a point for conciseness, brevity and frugality." - But it hides (visually) close parenthesis a lot. In any case, the code is the asker's very responsibility, changing the code by others would confuse the asker a lot. There is a [FAQ on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) about editing the other's code.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem recently.
In your `test/CmakeLists.txt`, `${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES}` should be used instead of `${Aramdillo_LIBRARIES}` (spelling mistake and upper case problem).